# Powershell create SQL login and user fails

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I'm trying to use Powershell to create an Azure database, login and user. 
Creating the database works. However I'm stuck at creating the login.

I use this code:

```
Connect-AzAccount

New-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ServerName $databaseServer -DatabaseName $databaseName -RequestedServiceObjectiveName $databaseTier

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString 'password'  -AsPlainText -Force     
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('user', $securePassword )

Add-SqlLogin -ServerInstance $databaseServer -LoginName $username -LoginType 'SqlLogin' -LoginPSCredential $credential -Enable -GrantConnectSql
```

This produces an error:

```
Add-SqlLogin : Failed to connect to server xxxxxxxxxxxxxx. 
    Add-SqlLogin -ServerInstance $databaseServer -LoginName $username ... 
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
    CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.String[]:String[]) [Add-SqlLogin], ConnectionFailureException  
    FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConnectionToServerFailed,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.Security.AddSqlLogin
```

I've tested the credentials that go into the $credential object. They are valid. 
(And since I can login to test them, it's also not a firewall problem)

I've also tried it without the -LoginPSCredential switch, hoping the AzAccount would be sufficient, but that produces the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you execute any queries against the server if you are not specifying the `ResourceGroupName`?

Comment: I am reasonably sure that the SqlServer module does not support logging in to an Azure resource with Credentials, at least it didn't used to. Looking at the options for [invoking a SQL command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps#example-11--connect-to-azure-sql-database--or-managed-instance--using-an-access-token), you have three choices: `Access Token`, `Managed Identity` and `Service Principal`

Comment: What I have said above may be different now. It might depend on the version of the SqlServer module and which version of [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15) it depends on.

Comment: I tried it with a service principal, didn't work either. (I hope I did it right)