# Can't Create Login In Newly Created Azure Sql Database From Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-pipelines, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

Trying to run the the following Powershell lines in a AzurePowerShell@5 Azure Pipeline task.

```
$database = New-AzSqlDatabase  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -ServerName $serverName `
    -DatabaseName $dbName `
    -RequestedServiceObjectiveName $databaseTier `
    -BackupStorageRedundancy $backupPolicy
```

and

```
Add-SqlLogin -ServerInstance $serverName -LoginName $loginName -LoginType 'SqlLogin' -LoginPSCredential $credential -Enable -GrantConnectSql -ConnectionTimeout 90
```

Gets me "Failed to connect to server " when running the Add-SqlLogin line.
I can connect to the server and databases fine using SSMS.

I was expecting to create a new login on the server, or at least get told I did not have permission to do so.

So far I have tried:

1. Adding a login manually to verify it is possible to create logins
2. Verifying server can be connected to in any fashion (it can)
3. Running the powershell script on my local machine (same result)

Comment: Is there any info beyond _Failed to connect to server_ Does adding `-DefaultDatabase` help?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Just the name of the server I was trying to connect to. DefaultDatabase does not change anything from what I can tell.

Comment: I suggest the usual troublshooting: use `Test-NetConnection` to confirm network connectivity. Then test a basic login with something like `Invoke-SqlCommand` to confirm you can log in as a sql user.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have managed to accomplish adding a login via Invoke-SqlCommand, and that will solve my problem for now. I hesitate to add an answer and accept it for that (or even if you did it) as that doesn't really get any closer to explaining how to use Add-SqlLogin to do so.

Comment: Great that you solved your problem. It seems like `Add-SqlLogin` just doesn't work properly and I wouldn't waste my timwe with a cmdlet that doesn't return useful error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try something similar to below code as a workaround:

```
$Creds = Get-Credential -Credential 'username@domain.com'
    $Username = $($Creds.GetNetworkCredential().UserName)
    $Password = $($Creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password)
    $Database = "testg"
    $Server = 'test.database.windows.net'
    $Port = 1433
    $cxnString = "Server=tcp:$Server,$Port;Database=$Database;Authentication=Active Directory Password;UID=$UserName;PWD=$Password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
    $query = "CREATE USER YourUser WITH PASSWORD = 'JRxuerCc(q'"
    $cxn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($cxnString)
    $cxn.Open()
    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $cxn)
    $cmd.CommandTimeout = 120
    $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $cxn.Close()
```

There are other users reporting the same error with Add-SqlLogin as you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70576270/powershell-create-sql-login-and-user-fails).